# RedBeanPHP multiple FK to the same table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, redbean

I'm using the latest version of RedBeanPHP. I'm modeling a football fixture structure. A single game, is performing by 2 teams and belong to a single game day (fixture in database).

```
$o = R::dispense('game');
$o->l = R::load('team',$l[$i]);
$o->v = R::load('team',$v[$i]);
$o->fixture = R::load('fixture',$id);
$id = R::store($o);
```

In the database, RB creates 2 Fk:

- index_foreignkey_game_team
- index_foreignkey_game_fixture

And after inset the games, this code dosn't work:

```
$games = R::find('games',"fixture_id='$ID'");
foreach( $games as $o ):
    echo $o->l->id; // Cannot access to the Local Team
    echo $o->v->id; // Cannot access to the Visit Team
endforeach
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm think is beacause the field hasn't got the same name as the fk table. For example, if i'm rename the field "l" has "team" it'work fine, but I need to have 2 teams, and i cant't obiously have two field named "team".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use an alias to tell RedBeanPHP what 'v' and 'l' are.

Here is how:

```
//for testing only...
list($team1, $team2) = R::dispense('team', 2);

$game = R::dispense('game');
$game->team = R::load('team',$team1);
$game->visitor = R::load('team',$team2);
$id = R::store($game);
$theGame = R::load('game', $id);


echo 'team1: '.$theGame->team->id;
echo PHP_EOL;
//here I tell RedBeanPHP: visitor IS a team.
echo 'team2: '.$theGame->fetchAs('team')->visitor->id;
```

For more details concerning aliasing: http://www.redbeanphp.com/aliasing

Hope this helps!

Cheers,
Gabor